# Javascript querySelector Problem Inside While Loop

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am trying to attach a countdown script to looped, dynamic divs. The countdown shows outside of the loop without issue, but console log shows queryselector is null inside the loop. If anyone can help it would be appreciated

```
var expiration = data[i]['expiration'];

function getTimeRemaining(expiration) {
  var t = Date.parse(expiration) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, expiration) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelectorAll('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelectorAll('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelectorAll('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelectorAll('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(expiration);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = t.hours;
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

initializeClock('clockdiv', expiration);


if (email == "") {

  if (promoType == "Banner") {
    $('#load-container-expiring').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoNameExpiringButton + '</div></div>');
    $('#load-container-expiring').append('<div><div class="wrap-content"><img class="mobile-banner-scale" id="visitor-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + '></div></div>');
    -- >>> Issue Here-- - > $('#load-container-expiring').append('<div id="clockdiv"><span class="days"></span> Days <span class="hours"></span> Hours <span class="minutes"></span> Minutes <span class="seconds"></span> Seconds</div>');
  }
```

Comment: Mind maybe moving the snippet to the code editor for a reproducible example? At first glance it looks like you're doing your queryselectors before the classes are assigned.

Comment: You attempt to access elements when calling *initializeClock* before they're created in the following *if* block.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you call `initializeClock('clockdiv', expiration)`, the `div` with id "clockdiv" does not exist yet. And so `clock` will be undefined, and 
`clock.querySelectorAll(...)` will generate an exception.

Move that  `initializeClock('clockdiv', expiration)` below the code that adds that "clockdiv" element to the DOM.

Also fix the first `secondsSpan.innerHTML =` to be `minutesSpan.innerHTML =`

Comment: Thanks. I made the fix and moved  the function below the load function. Tried many locations. The error is gone, but no data shows in the countdowns. I moved the whole all the countdown functions to the bottom of the page and same thing. No error, but no countdown data coming through.